# Ubuntu Changed to Ubuntu Kylin?

Tags: 16.04, compiz, plymouth, kylin

I installed the CompizConfig Settings Manager, but I didn't confirm any changes in it other than testing the fade, and when I shutdown my computer the Ubuntu Kylin splash appeared, and it did it again when I booted back in. And when I reached the login, it was the login for Kylin. The desktop and everything else works fine. I tried deleting the Plymouth for Kylin, but it just made Plymouth crash, and the login screen was still stuck as Kylin. How do I revert back to my original Ubuntu splash and login?

Comment: Run `dpkg -l | grep kylin` in a terminal to see what Ubuntu Kylin packages you have installed accidentally by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

same happened with me, apparently I was trying out the theme etc but I didn't configure them, I don't shut down my system often, so I forgot about it, when my system froze while coding I had to hard reboot, and then Ubuntu Kylin screen appeared, I was freaked out.

then I checked in the kylin packages and removed them, all fixed.